# mailto: link not working on mobile devices in IOS

Tags: javascript, html, email

I want to open native/default email app on mobile devices on click of a button. The function goes as follows:

```
function openLink() { 
  return window.open(`mailto:${emailAddress}?subject=${subject}&body=${body}`, 'mailtoWindow')
}
```

Nothing happens if opened on chrome on a mobile device, on other browsers it opens default/native mail client.

Comment: Do you check in the simulator or real device?

Comment: @ForamTrada real device

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" name="emailLink" id="emailLink">Email</a>

$(function () {
  $('#emailLink').on('click', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    alert("Huh");
    var email = 'test@theearth.com';
    var subject = 'Circle Around';
    var emailBody = 'Some blah';
    window.location = 'mailto:' + email + '?subject=' + subject + '&body=' +   emailBody;
  });
});
```